# Elasticsearch – combine ids query with must_not clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, retire

I’d like to combine `ids` query with `must_not` clause. I’m using (re)tire gem with rails application.

I’m doing something like this:

```
query do
  ids ["foo", "bar", "test"]
end
```

Which works. However, when I’m trying to combine it with `must_not` clause, I’m getting error – `must_not` works only withing `boolean` scope, which does not include `ids` query. Is there any way to combine that two queries?

Answer (score 9):

The ES query that you need to use is this one:

```
GET /some_index/some_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": ["foo", "bar", "test"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "whatever"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, you need boolean scope, a `must` with your `ids` and a `must_not` with your must not match queries.